# Encoding with FFmpeg using a FIFO

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm trying to convert Flac audio file to AAC file using command line.

So I wrote this

```
    ffmpeg -i input.flac temp.wav
    faac -q 120 -o output.m4a temp.wav
```

It's working fine. Now I want to do the same using fifo, so I'm writing this

```
   mkfifo temp.wav
   ffmpeg -i input.flac temp.wav  &   faac -q 120 -o output.m4a temp.wav
```

And it's freezing.

So could you tall me what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks a lot, and sorry for my English.

Comment: Why can't you simply pipe them: ffmpeg -i input.flac -f wav pipe: |  faac -q 120 -o output.m4a -

Comment: Thanks, it's work.But could you tell me what I was doing wrong, and what is the syntax of making such pipe?. Thanks a lot. (I'm just a newbie in this) :)

Comment: This is a question about running existing applications, not writing new ones, so I'm voting to move to superuser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FFmpeg doesn't support FIFOs, you'll have to use a pipe as suggested by @adamax , follow up on [`FFmpeg bug #1663`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1663) if you want/need FIFO support in FFmpeg.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but just want to chip in and point out that, unlike the accepted conclusion that *"FFmpeg doesn't support FIFOs"*, which is over-ten-year-old, I tested just now and found it is working.

As per https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1663,

> it should work. At least for raw stream inputs...

which is what I'm using. (The tool that I'm using to produce the .wav file doesn't support piping to stdout, but only write to files, thus I have to use named pipe in my case)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-y` switch. Some versions of ffmpeg hang while testing the existence of the named pipe. The `y` switch would be a work-around.